# pass variable to dynamically populated drop down

Tags: javascript, html, forms

We have an online application html form that pulls the open positions into a menu/list select field from an xml file. You can see the form here: [enter link description here](http://www.citizensmemorial.com/careers/online-app.html)

For each open position there is a job posting page with an apply now button which links to the application page. We'd like to pass the position to the menu/list select field in the form when a user hits the apply now button.

So If I make a form on the job posting page, and use a hidden field to hold the position from that page, then how do I pass that variable to the online application to select the position.

Comment: please post what code you have tried

Comment: @nandu \code\ $.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}

// example.com?param1=id&amp;param2=Apply Now
$.urlParam('param1'); // id
$.urlParam('param2');        // Apply Now

console.log(decodeURIComponent($.urlParam('id')));  


$('#opening').val(decodeURIComponent($.urlParam('id'))); \code\

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the default value to your select box.

After you load your page,

```
document.getElementById("selectbox").value = hiddensValue;
```

Comment: I set up the form on the job posting page and when I hit the apply now button, I get this taken to this url: http://www.citizensmemorial.com/careers/online-app.html?hiddenField=2816&ApplyNow=Apply+Now  How do I define the hiddenField variable from the url?

Comment: I don't get what you ask. You are asking how to pass the value to the new form ?

Comment: Yes. I have the value in the url, but I don't know how to pass that to the form. If I used the code you've added above, how does the page know what the hiddenValue is? Don't I have to define it somewhere?